# Can't grab edges in sculpting mode

Tags: edges, sculpting

[image]

I'm using blender 4.0. I can't grab edges it moving everything except them.

Comment: Why use Sculpt mode when a tweak like this can be done in Edit mode with proportional editing enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Grab Tool in Sculpt Mode will grab vertices not edges.

Comment: I think i could grab bottom part before and now i can't